# Convert Product Array into New Product array Formate

Tags: javascript

My current output is:

```js
const VR1 = [{
    content_ids: "323654284",
    item_price: 131.1, 
    quantity: 1,
}];
```

What I wanted to be get into this format:

```js
const res = [{
    "content_ids": "323654284",
    "item_price": "131.1",
    "quantity": "1",
}];
```

I tried this code:

```js
const res = JSON.stringify(VR1);
```

But my result is:

```js
"[{\"content_ids\":\"323654284\",\"item_price\":131.1,\"quantity\":1}]"
```

Comment: Do you want to make your numbers strings (why?), otherwise normal json “stringify”?

Comment: @DaveNewton What to achieve this result - Result Looking this Format: [{"content_ids": "323654284", "item_price": "131.1", "quantity: "1"}]

Comment: You want to convert all values to string ?

Comment: @Pompedup All values to string and wanted to achive - [{"content_ids": "323654284", "item_price": "131.1", "quantity: "1"}]

Comment: @Pompedup Yes, I need this exactly , I tried this code in GTM, It's saying does not in correct formate - Google Tag Manager - This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function.

Comment: If your comment refers to the current answer—don’t use an arrow function then, use a regular function.

Comment: @DaveNewton We need a regular function

Comment: So use a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```js
var VR1 = [{ content_ids: "323654284", item_price: 131.1, quantity: 1 }]

VR1.forEach((content) => Object.keys(content).forEach((key) => content[key] = String(content[key])))


console.log(VR1)
```